# performance of whereBetween method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

please explain :

what is difference in performance , when we use

```
whereBetween("col",[value1,value2])
```

or

```
where("col",">=",value1)->where("col","<=",value2)
```

in large data ?

actually comparing those query methods.

Comment: What have you tried to compare these methods? Have you checked whether they produce the same query?

Comment: yes i checked.but i want to know difference of performance.if i use whereBetween is better or use another way for searching in large data?

Answer (score 2):

The first one translates into SQL `"col between value1,value2"` and the other translates to `col >= value1 and col <=value2`. You can see the generated query string attaching "toSql" instead of "get" in the eloquent line

```
echo Classname::whereBetween("col",[value1,value2])->toSql();
```

So, that actually depends on what is more efficient in SQL. But i don't think there is any difference, no matter the data being small or large.

Comment: iam not expert but they kinda the same https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html "A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators"

Comment: i want to know difference of performance.if i use whereBetween is better or use another way for searching in large data?